# sticky header and footer

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to have a sticky header and footer on my template, which works but i have an issue in that the id="page" does not always scroll under the header!

Here is the site, http://zmgc.net/

I see that there is an issue with elements which have position="relative" such as the tabs and the "Patricia signed..." box item, as an example.

```
.box ul.supports-list li.last {
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
```

How do i fix the id="page" so that all the elements within it always scroll under both the header and the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a z-index for the header like this:

```
#hd{
z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` for #header and #footer, and `overflow:hidden/auto` for body/#page.

In my example you just need fixed heights for header and footer

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/uNVd8/)

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:30px 0 40px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
#header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background: red;
}
#footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background: blue;
}
#page{
  overflow:auto;
  height:100%;
  background: green;
} ​
```